# Unable to open camera from ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the demo [camera](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/use-android-ios-camera-ionic-framework/)

app opens correctly but on clicking photo button nothing happens

Comment: getting any errors?

Comment: I do not hav any idea how to show error logs on chrome or anywhere while testing on a real device. I tried --livereload but it works only upon emulator